# Vagrant is using all chef attribute files instead of just default

Tags: chef-infra, vagrant

I think there may be something fundamental that Im missing when using Vagrant, Chef, OpsWorks.

My understanding is that when you have a recipe that is used by OpsWorks, you can assume that attribute files with the same name as a node will be applied to that node.

But when I start the same VM in Vagrant, Im not only getting attribute values from files other than Default, but Im getting attribute values from Cookbooks that Im not even adding in my Vagrant Chef add_recipe call.

I understand that OpsWorks is free to use conventions above and beyond what Vagrant would use.  But what is a practical way in which you can run VMs of cookbooks locally using the same code base that you have OpsWorks pulling from?

Is there something obvious I'm not understanding?

Answer (score 1):

Chef always loads all attribute files from the `attributes/` directory. That's not Vagrant's fault, that's how `chef-client` and `chef-solo` behave.